# Add a Tab to a Company's Page - Programmatically

Tags: tabs, fbml

I really need help with this... is it doable? Is it possible to add a Tab to a Company's Page programatically (like FBML, where the users writes their own HTML code)? Such as the C# SDK or through some other SDK? How would I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Facebook Graph API allows it with permission "manage_pages".

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs

> You can install a profile_tab at the end of the current list of
>   installed tabs for a page by issuing an HTTP POST request to
>   PAGE_ID/tabs with a Page Access Token.

Javascript SDK:

```
FB.api('/' + PAGE_ID + '/tabs','post',
{ app_id: APP_ID, access_token: PAGE_TOKEN }, function (response) { });
```

Otherwise you could POST the same data via C# and a valid page access token. You get the page access token from /user/accounts: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Answer (score 0):

From the research I've done, I don't think there's a way to do it programmatically directly.  However, you can use the following link:

http://facebook.com/add.php?pi_key=YOUR_APP_KEY&pages=1&page=YOUR_PAGE_ID